# Show / Hide div on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would need to show my div (footer-nav) on 2200 px after scrolling 
& then hide it again on 2800 px.

All good with my code in the initial part, 
so my element is shown after 2200px and hides when the mouse does not move for two seconds,

**but I would like also to hide completely my div when reaching 2800px scroll.**

Have a look at my snippet, would be great to trigger the event each time I scroll up or down the window:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
function footer()
{
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if(scroll > 2200)
    { 
        $(".footer-nav").fadeIn("slow").addClass("show");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".footer-nav").fadeOut("slow").removeClass("show");
    }

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('.footer-nav').is(':hover')) {
            footer();
        }


        else
        {
            $(".footer-nav").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }, 2000));
}
footer();});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is easier for everyone to give you a solution if you make a fiddle with your issue!

Comment: try updating your if condition to if(scroll > 2200 && scroll < 2800)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
function footer()
{
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if(scroll > 2200 && scroll < 2800)   <-- this line
    { 
        $(".footer-nav").fadeIn("slow").addClass("show");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".footer-nav").fadeOut("slow").removeClass("show");
    }

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('.footer-nav').is(':hover')) {
            footer();
        }
        else
        {
            $(".footer-nav").fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }, 2000));
}
footer();});
```